# find from last element's(object) field in array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to find data conditionally with mongoose by checking `state` field last element of `history` array.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ff4360b3a1119002a6b8e04"),
        "name" : "sample"
        "history" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b0402a92b2a18116bf51de"),
                "state" : "pending"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b0402a92b2a18116bf51fn"),
                "state" : "completed"
            }
        ],

    }
```

I try with following,

```
collection.find({$expr: {$eq: [{"$arrayElemAt": ["stateHistory", -1]}, "completed"]}})
```

Is there way to do this using `find` function without using aggregation?

Comment: just pass `$history.state` instead of `stateHistory`, like `{"$arrayElemAt": ["$history.state", -1]}`

Comment: It is working for me... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$where`

```
collection.find({
    $where: function(){
        return this.history[this.history.length-1].state === "completed"
    }
})
```